# References for Exterior Differential Systems for physicists

Tags: resource-recommendations, mathematical-physics, differential-equations

Many problems in classical mechanics, classical and quantum field theory among others require the study of systems of partial differential equations where questions like existence and uniqueness cannot be answered with the typical counting-equations/variables arguments - questions which have physical relevance and that need to be addressed before going to numerics. For instance, problems in surface mechanics always involve the Gauss-Codazzi equations which is a non-linear overdetermined system of PDE.

The most powerful technology to properly study general systems of PDEs are Exterior Differential Systems, and there are some canonical references in the mathematics literature like Bryant et. al. I found this challenging for a standard theoretical physics graduate because it requires a solid background in non-conventional math topics for physics like commutative algebra and number theory, so I wonder if there is any reference treating EDS for physicist.

Comment: I'll be honest, I know differential forms very well, but never have heard of exterior differential systems. And a quick Google search does not give much. So, you may have to start with a paper such as [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.6247.pdf](Exterior Differential Systems for Field Theories), and take a look at the references since there seems to be a good mixture of math-ph and hep-th references there. Also, going through Bryant's textbook, anytime you have a math question, go to their respective StackExchange and ask questions (that's how I learned cohomology). But good luck, seems interesting!